# Loop over all possible ways to alter a numpy array- Chess Programming

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, chess

I have the following function that takes chess_position as an input, chess_position is an 8x8 numpy array.

naive_possible_moves returns a list of tuples of starting square and finishing square.

move_a_piece takes the starting square, finishing square, the Board and whose turn it is and then alters the Board accordingly, outputting a numpy array of the new position

```
def states_after_move(chess_position):
    
   for move in naive_possible_moves(chess_position, 'White'):
      print(move_a_piece(move[0], move[1], chess_position, 'White'))
```

For example my Board, looks like:

```
Board = array([[21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 41, 31, 21],
              [11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11],
              [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
              [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
              [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
              [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
              [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
              [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 40, 30, 20]])
```

When i run the following code:

```
states_after_move(Board)
```

I get:

```
[[21 31 41 51 61 41 31 21]
 [11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0 10 10 10 10 10 10 10]
 [20 30 40 50 60 40 30 20]]
False
[[21 31 41 51 61 41 31 21]
 [11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [10 10  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0 10 10 10 10 10 10]
 [20 30 40 50 60 40 30 20]]
False
[[21 31 41 51 61 41 31 21]
 [11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [10 10 10  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 10 10 10 10 10]
 [20 30 40 50 60 40 30 20]]
False
[[21 31 41 51 61 41 31 21]
 [11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [10 10 10 10  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0 10 10 10 10]
 [20 30 40 50 60 40 30 20]]
False
[[21 31 41 51 61 41 31 21]
 [11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [10 10 10 10 10  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0 10 10 10]
 [20 30 40 50 60 40 30 20]]
False
[[21 31 41 51 61 41 31 21]
 [11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [10 10 10 10 10 10  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0 10 10]
 [20 30 40 50 60 40 30 20]]
False
[[21 31 41 51 61 41 31 21]
 [11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [10 10 10 10 10 10 10  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0 10]
 [20 30 40 50 60 40 30 20]]
False
[[21 31 41 51 61 41 31 21]
 [11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [20 30 40 50 60 40 30 20]]
False
False
False
False
False

...
```

The Problem is it tries to run every single move in order instead of running each move on the initial board, to give all possible states for white after the first move.

I tried this:

```
def states_after_move(chess_position):
    chess_position_ = chess_position.copy()
    for move in naive_possible_moves(chess_position, 'White'):
        print(move_a_piece(move[0], move[1], chess_position_, 'White'))
```

However it did not make a difference. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post `naive_possible_moves`?

Comment: Apparently `move_a_piece` is modifying the board, rather than returning a copy of the board with the change.

Comment: make the copy each time you move: `move_a_piece(move[0], move[1], chess_position.copy(), 'White')`

Comment: Be sure you perform a deep copy and not a shallow one.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the problem, but try this and see if it works. The difference here is that we use deepcopy() which instead of copying just the 'top' array, it creates a new copy of every array and object in that array as well.

using regular copy() may only copy the top array, and not the 8 arrays of numbers in each element.

try this too see if this works:

```
import copy #<--- NEED TO IMPORT COPY
def states_after_move(chess_position):
    chess_position_ = copy.deepcopy(chess_position) #<--- CHANGED HERE
    for move in naive_possible_moves(chess_position, 'White'):
        print(move_a_piece(move[0], move[1], chess_position_, 'White'))
```